# Background image doesn't fit well

Tags: jquery, image, css, jquery-mobile

I want to have a background image in my footer. I have chosen two pictures from the internet that are very close to my case. However, it doesn't cover everything and there is a line in the borders that I want to get rid of (a grey one). Here is the [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/gsamaras/h7gxpqn0/22/).

Here is a solution I've tried, but didn't change things:

```
.ui-footer {
    background: #000;
    background-image: url("http://powered.gr/neosite/images/demo/slide-1.png");
    background-size: 105% 105%;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check this out
[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/h7gxpqn0/35/)

```
html { 
      background: url(images/bg.jpg) no-repeat center center fixed; 
      -webkit-background-size: cover;
      -moz-background-size: cover;
      -o-background-size: cover;
      background-size: cover;
    }
```

Works in:

Safari 3+

Chrome Whatever+

IE 9+

Opera 10+ (Opera 9.5 supported background-size but not the keywords)

Firefox 3.6+ (Firefox 4 supports non-vendor prefixed version)

Courtesy: [CSS Tricks](https://css-tricks.com/perfect-full-page-background-image/)

Answer (score 0):

Try appending `style` element to `body` setting `#footer` `background-color` , `border-color` to `transparent` , set `.ui.page` `background-repeat: no-repeat;`

```
 $(function(){$("<style>",{"text":"#footer{background-color:transparent;border-color: transparent;"}).appendTo("body")})
```

jsfiddle http://jsfiddle.net/h7gxpqn0/37/

Comment: Use of important in a place where there is not much complexity is bad.`https://css-tricks.com/when-using-important-is-the-right-choice/`.

Comment: there is no need for such big stacks. `Footer` tag alone can handle stack start `footer { } `. Moreover he has data-* in place which makes it very easy to avoid stacking. Something from BEM methodology. Thank You